# Error with xib file

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

This is my code:

```
for view in arrayViews {

        self.addChildViewController(view)

        self.scroll.addSubview(view.view)

        view.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

And I get this error at the line: `self.scroll.addSubview(view.view)`:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

By the way scroll is a `UIScrollView`.

Comment: view.view is nil in some point

Comment: or `self.scroll` is `nil`.

Comment: self.scroll is connected to outlet   and what is view.view it should be view?

Comment: `view.view` probably cannot be `nil` (probably `UIViewController.view`) therefore it's probably the `self.scroll`.